# Parse an html page with XML in python

Tags: python, html, xml, parsing

I'm trying to put python parsing this XML code from an HTML page:

```
<weather>
    <loc mobiurl="http://foreca.mobi/?lon=-8.6110&lat=41.1496&source=navi/" url="http://foreca.com/?lon=-8.6110&lat=41.1496&source=navi/">
        <obs station="Porto / Pedras Rubras" dist="11 km NW" dt="2013-03-06 17:00:00" t="14" tf="14" s="d320" wn="S" ws="8" p="997" rh="94" v="5000"/>
        <fc dt="2013-03-07" tx="16" tn="11" s="d220"/>
        <fc dt="2013-03-08" tx="15" tn="10" s="d220"/>
        <fc dt="2013-03-09" tx="15" tn="10" s="d220"/>
    </loc>
</weather>
```

I want to get the information on `dr`, `s`, `tx` and `tn` fields but I don't know how to do it with XML functions. I try to read the HTML file and then create and arrow to store the content after the paths said before but I can't get it working.

Is there any easy way to get the data with python?

Comment: I'm a little confused by your question. Is that data from an XML document or an HTML document? If it *is* from an HTML document, how is it embedded?

Comment: There are no `tr` attributes in this example, is that a typo?

Comment: it is not well-formed xml. The ampersand character (`&`) must be escaped as `&amp;`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters it was a typo. I mean "dt", not "tr"...

Comment: @Robᵩ the xml file is on this web page: [link](http://fnw2.foreca.com/showdata.php?lon=-8.6110&lat=41.1496&format=xml/pedro-aaltoweb-mar13)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some HTML scraping is easily done with pyparsing, using that library's `makeHTMLTags` method (`makeHTMLTags` returns a pair of expressions, for opening and closing tags, but in your example, only the opening tag is needed):

```
from pyparsing import makeHTMLTags

fcTag = makeHTMLTags("fc")[0]
tagAttrs = 'dt s tx tn'.split()

for match in fcTag.searchString(htmltext):
    print ' '.join("%s:%s" % (attr,match[attr]) for attr in tagAttrs)
```

Prints:

```
dt:2013-03-07 s:d220 tx:16 tn:11
dt:2013-03-08 s:d220 tx:15 tn:10
dt:2013-03-09 s:d220 tx:15 tn:10
```

This makes it easy to incorporate this fragment parser with pyparsing's other features, such as run-time parse actions, semantic checking, etc.

**EDIT**

If you want all the dt's, s's, etc. in their own respective lists (in Python, we call them "lists", not "vectors"), do this:

```
dtArray = []
sArray = []
txArray = []
tnArray = []
for match in fcTag.searchString(htmltext):
    dtArray.append(match.dt)
    sArray.append(match.s)
    txArray.append(match.tx)
    tnArray.append(match.tn)
    print ' '.join("%s:%s" % (attr,match[attr]) for attr in tagAttrs)
```

I've seen code like this before, and it is a poor data structure pattern. You access the value of the i'th entry of the original table by getting `dtArray[i]`, `sArray[i]`, etc.

Please consider instead one of the several structured types offered by Python. You have several to choose from:

A. Use dicts.

```
fcArray = []
for match in fcTag.searchString(htmltext):
    fcArray.append(dict((attr,match[attr]) for attr in tagAttrs))
```

Now to get at the i'th entry, just get `fc = fcArray[i]`, and access the `fc['dt']`, `fc['s']` etc. values from that dict.

B. Use namedtuples.

```
from collections import namedtuple
FCData = namedtuple("FCData", tagAttrs)

fcArray = []
for match in fcTag.searchString(htmltext):
    fcArray.append(FCData(*(match[attr] for attr in tagAttrs)))
```

You again use `fc = fcArray[i]` to get the i'th entry, but now you access the values using `fc.dt`, `fc.s`, etc. I find this form to be cleaner-looking than the dict form, but there are some restrictions. All the tag names have to be legal Python identifiers, so if you have a tag "rise/run", then you can't use a namedtuple. Also, namedtuples are immutable - you can't take an existing FCData `fc` and assign into its `dt` field with `fc.dt = "new datetime value"`. dicts on the other hand would allow this.

C. Use objects. The simplest is a "bag"-type object that creates empty object instances, which you than add attributes to through simple assignment or setattr calls:

```
class FCData(object): pass

fcArray = []
for match in fcTag.searchString(htmltext):
    fc = FCdata()
    for attr in tagAttrs:
        setattr(fc, attr, match[attr])
    fcArray.append(fc)
```

You get the i'th entry with `fc = fcArray[i]`, and like the namedtuple, you get the attributes using `fc.dt` and so on. But you can also modify the attributes if need be, and the assignment `fc.dt = "new datetime value"` would work.

D. Just use the objects created by pyparsing's searchString method.

```
fcArray = fcTag.searchString(htmltext)
```

pyparsing returns `ParseResults`, and it combines the behavior of both dicts and namedtuples. Just like before you access the i'th entry with `fc = fcArray[i]`. You can read the `dt` attribute with `fc.dt` or `fc['dt']`. You can read `fc.dt`, but you can't assign to it, just like the namedtuple.  You *can* assign to `fc['dt']`, just like the dict.

Comment: Apparently this is working. Now I'll transform this and try do adapt it on Raspberry Pi.

Thank you very much :D

Comment: I'm trying to "save" each value in a different vector, but I'm stuck...
I want one vector for each date, another for each "s", etc, but I'm only saving the last line of each element. Anyone can help me? :(

Comment: Thanks Paul for the help. But now, when I run the script I got this error: "tnAray.append(match.tn)
NameError: name 'tnAray' is not defined"... I had imported the array module also.

Comment: EDIT: Forget this! There's a missing "r" in the word "Array" lol THANK YOU VERY MUCH Paul! :D This is working just fime with the first and more poor option :D

Comment: Ha, fixed the typo, and now you have learned a little bit about fixing bugs for yourself too!

Comment: I've learned a lot this weekend with this project thanks to all the help. Thank you very very much for the help you gave to me! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you can extract just the weather tags easily, you can use the [`xml.etree.ElementTree` API](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) which comes with Python.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.fromstring(weatherdata)

for fcelem in tree.findall('.//fc'):
    print fcelem.attrib['tx'], fcelem.attrib['tn']
```

If you want to extract it from the HTML document, then it depends on how well-formed the HTML is. If it is a XHTML document, the ElementTree API can handle it fine.

Otherwise, you'll need to switch to a HTML parser instead. You could install the [`lxml` library](http://lxml.de); that library supports the same ElementTree API but has a dedicated HTML parser included.

You could also use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) for an alternate HTML API. In fact, `lxml` and `BeautifulSoup` can work in concert giving you a choice of APIs for your tasks; use whichever is easier for you.

Both  `lxml` and `BeautifulSoup` are external libraries.

Comment: `.fromstring()` return an Element, not tree. `.findall('fc')` doesn't work here. You could use `.findall('.//fc')` or `.iter('fc')` instead.

Comment: Or there is a very simple HTMLParser in python distributions.

Comment: @ondra: There is, but it is *too* simple. See http://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html, but I cannot recommend it. It's API is cumbersome, and it does not deal well with broken HTML.